# What does the notation $\widehat{E}_n $ means in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading the book "Spectra of Graphs" by Andries E. Brouwer and Willem H. Haemers, in which the graphs $ \widehat{E}_n $ is referenced, but not given for every n.

When Showing some examples, for n = 6,7,8 they look like this (ignore the numbers near the vertecies):

[image]

I would love to know if there is a general description of this graph.

Comment: The graphs are defined by their pictures; they arise in the context of root systems.

Comment: I understand that they are defined by their pictures but I don't see the general case for every n, aside from the values given. For example I don't know what $\widehat{E}_{10}$ looks like.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear enough. There are only those three graphs, there is no $E_{10}$.